# How do I get a Microsoft Sidewinder Precision 2 joystick to work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, game-controller, peripherals

When I plug it in, Windows 8 doesn't recognize the Microsoft Sidewinder Precision 2 joystick as being plugged in at all and it doesn't work. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up shutting off the computer (actually, just sleeping it, but you could try shutting it off). With the computer off I plugged in the joystick, started it up, and Windows 8 found the joystick, installed the correct drivers, and I was good to go.

Screenshot of the joystick recognized in Windows 8:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/523843/380318) also works for Windows 7 with Sidewinder joysticks. If Windows sees the device but doesn't recognize it as a game controller, go into the Control Panel and uninstall the driver or the device. Then connect the joystick, restart Windows, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, please try an USB port that's directly on the mainboard. The joystick draws quite some power and secondary connected 'front' ports or ports on a hub do not always work.